# How to expose custom DTO crud repository with Spring data REST?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, dto, spring-data-rest

I don't want to expose my model classes (jpa entities), rather different subset of their attributes with different data transport objects (DTOs).
The idea is `DTO CrudRepository <-> JpaRepository <-> entities`, and I want to expose via Spring Data REST the `DTO CrudRepository`.

Example:

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<User> users;
    // other attributes

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    // other getters and setters

}
```

**JpaRepository:**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface GroupDao extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {
}
```

**DTO:**

```
public class GroupWithoutRelationsDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**DTO CrudRepository:**

```
public interface GroupDtoDao extends CrudRepository<GroupWithoutRelationsDto, Long> {
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Repository
public class GroupDtoDaoImpl extends GenericDtoDao<GroupWithoutRelationsDto, Group, Long> implements GroupDtoDao {

    @Autowired
    private GroupDao groupDao;

    @Override
    protected CrudRepository<Group, Long> getModelDao() {
        return groupDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected <S extends GroupWithoutRelationsDto> Long getDtoId(S dto) {
        return dto.getId();
    }

    @Override
    protected Long getModelId(Group model) {
        return model.getId();
    }

    @Override
    protected <S extends GroupWithoutRelationsDto> S modelToDto(Group model, S dto) {
        dto.setId(model.getId());
        dto.setName(model.getName());
        return dto;
    }

    @Override
    protected <S extends GroupWithoutRelationsDto> Group dtoToModel(S dto, Group model) {
        model.setId(dto.getId());
        model.setName(dto.getName());
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected Group newModel() {
        return new Group();
    }

    @Override
    protected GroupWithoutRelationsDto newDto() {
        return new GroupWithoutRelationsDto();
    }

}
```

GenericDtoDao:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public abstract class GenericDtoDao<D, M, ID extends Serializable> implements CrudRepository<D, ID> {

    protected abstract CrudRepository<M, ID> getModelDao();

    protected abstract <S extends D> ID getDtoId(S dto);

    protected abstract ID getModelId(M model);

    protected abstract <S extends D> S modelToDto(M model, S dto);

    protected abstract <S extends D> M dtoToModel(S dto, M model);

    protected abstract M newModel();

    protected abstract D newDto();

    @Override
    public D findOne(ID id) {
        return modelToDto(getModelDao().findOne(id), newDto());
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends D> S save(S entity) {
        Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity must not be null!");
        if (getDtoId(entity) == null) {
            return create(entity);
        }
        return update(entity);
    }

    protected <S extends D> S create(S entity) {
        Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity must not be null!");
        if (getDtoId(entity) != null) {
            Assert.isTrue(!exists(getDtoId(entity)), "The entity ID must be null or not exist!");
        }
        return modelToDto(getModelDao().save(dtoToModel(entity, newModel())), entity);
    }

    protected <S extends D> S update(S entity) {
        Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity must not be null!");
        M model = getModelDao().findOne(getDtoId(entity));
        Assert.notNull(model, "The entity must exist!");
        return modelToDto(getModelDao().save(dtoToModel(entity, model)), entity);
    }

    // other CrudRepository methods

}
```

In this example I want to expose GroupDtoDao with Spring data REST.

In other beans I can autowire both GroupDao and GroupDtoDao, so both are managed by Spring's context. If I don't annotate `GroupDao` with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)` the JpaRepository is exposed as REST service, so I suppose Spring data REST is well configured.

How can I tell it to expose my custom CrudRepository?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm interested in the answer as well but don't have a clean solution. My best idea was to provide a custom JSON ObjectMapper, and inside the mapper do the mapping to DTO and write out the DTO instead.

Comment: I haven't find an automatic solution yet, I still have a custom CrudRestController which wraps my DtoDaos methods

Answer (score 2):

There is [a JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-512) to clarify how to do this.

For now, the SDR team says "We generally recommend to just use Jackson mixins to hook in custom serializers, customize output etc. See the [Spring RESTBucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/JacksonCustomizations.java#L48) for an example."