# Return custom-typed object from JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have the following repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends BaseDAO<User> {
    Collection<User> findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

    @Query("select new com.data.CustomUser(upper(substring(u.lastName, 1, 1)) as initial, count(*)) from User u join u.chats c where c.business=:business group by upper(substring(u.lastName, 1, 1)) order by initial")
    List<CustomUser> getContactsIndex(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

which is exposed with Spring Data REST. The `User` object is a managed entity, while `CustomUser` not and as you can see, it's build on-fly by using custom query.

Once I want to call that function, it fails with `Persistent entity must not be a null!` exception. Is there any way to implement this behavior?

P.S. Expose `CustomUser` with separate repository is impossible because it is not a managed entity.

Comment: Is this only for Spring Data Rest or are you calling this method also in different places.

Comment: @M.Deinum Only Spring Data Rest. Previously this piece of code worked fine as a standalone DAO

Comment: Then you could use [Projections or Excerpt](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections) instead of doing it with JPA.

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, this object based on SQL query, it's not a composite one

Answer (score 1):

One challenge with using Spring Data Rest is when you hit an edge case and you don't know whether you've hit a bug or whether you're just outside the scope of what the library is intended for. In this case I think you are at the edge of what SDR will easily do for you, and it's time to implement your own controller.

Spring Data Rest is looking for an Entity - in your case a User - as the return type for ALL methods in the repository to expose under /entities/search, and breaks when it doesn't find that entity type. The User it wants to serialize isn't there, hence the "Persistent entity must not be null".

The way around this is to write a simple @Controller that has a @RequestMapping for the exact same url exposed by the repository method. This will override the SDR generated implementation for that url, and from that you can return whatever you want.

Your implementation might look something like this:

```
@Controller
public class CustomUserController {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    @Inject
    public CustomUserController(UserRepository repo) {
        repository = repo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/search/getContactsIndex", method = GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody List<CustomUser> getContactsIndex(@RequestParam String email) {
        return repository.getContactsIndex(email);
    }

}
```

Be aware that there is a "recommended" way to override functionality this way. There is an [open issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-535) to document the best way to do this.

Comment: I'd also like to add a reference to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428573/how-to-expose-custom-dto-crud-repository-with-spring-data-rest